# FFMPEg and gcc problem

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ffmpeg, compilation

The problem is this: I wrote a simple program that uses FFMPEG. compile as follows:

```
gcc -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -c test.c

gcc -lavcodec -lavformat -Lavut -o test test.o
```

Compiled without problems, test file appears, but when you start:
. / test
An error occurs:

. / test: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.53: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

At what ffmpeg was originally built and installed and the file libavcodec.so.53 there. In what may be the problem?

Comment: Just a comment: You should always put the libraries last when linking: `gcc -o test test.o -lavcodec -lavformat -Lavut`. When you're running this, make sure you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include `avut`. Just run `ldd ./test` to see where the loader expects the libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be linking against libraries in a custom library directory, `-Lavut`.

Check where your loader looks for the executable's libraries:

```
ldd ./test
```

If any of them are in non-standard directories (and `ldd` indicates that a particular library couldn't be found), append those to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/work/avut ./test
```

If you like, you can hardcode the library path into the executable with the `-rpath` linker option, e.g. `gcc ... -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/tmp/work/avut`.

Comment: Everything is OK. Help: LD_LIBRARY_PATH = / usr / local / lib. / Test

Thanks:)

Comment: @Kyborg2011 This command won't work by itself, you need to use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/library/dir`. Without using `export`, the environment variable won't be visible to the program.